# TaxonomyWebTaggingControl, return selected term with parents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, managed-metadata

`TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.Text` returns label of selected metadata with the picker.

The label form is `mylabel|GUID` even if the term has multiple parents.

I need a simple way, from `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl`, to get term with parents (ex: `parentsofparentslabel:parentlabel:mylabel|GUID`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get terms with parents just set `IsIncludePathData` property to `true`, once you changed it to true you will get parents terms guid(s), remember only Guid(s) e.g.

```
Label1|Guid1|Guid2(Level2)|Guid(Level1).
```